# "It wasn’t always like that" / "It hasn’t always been like that"

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

> It **wasn’t** always like that.
>
> It **hasn’t always been** like that.

If I understand correctly, the first sentence tells us the situation can't be changed now or in future. But what tells the second sentence?

If we compare it with another situation (the following sentences), there is a possibility to change the situation now or in the nearest future (if we speak about Present Perfect):

> I haven't had any lunch. = afternoon isn't over.
>
> I didn't have lunch today. = afternoon is over. It's evening or night.

Comment: It's not about the amount of time. It is about the fact that it is past without saying when in the past. I haven't had any lunch. = tells you that at the moment I'm telling you this I have not eaten (in the afternoon) but does not tell you WHEN. COMPARE: I didn't have lunch today. I skipped it. In that case, the lunch would have had to have been eaten at a specific time.

Comment: @Lambie, It's not perfectly correlated to my question. But there is hidden information about the time in your examples.  I haven't had any lunch. = afternoon isn't over. I didn't have lunch today. = afternoon is over. It's evening or night.

Comment: I haven't taken the exam yet. I took the exam. It's always the **same thing**. At the time of speaking, x happened in the past which is **undefined**. It is just past. I haven't responded to this properly. Compare: I responded to this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It hasn't always been like that.

The same sentence reworded: "*It is not true that it has always been like that*".

In more natural words, it means at some time or times in the past, it wasn't like that, and strongly implies that it *is* like that now.

Comment: If I understand you correctly when we speak about "It wasn’t always like that.", we don't know it is an actual situation or not, unlike the sentence with Present Perfect. Right?

Comment: @Sergei What do you mean by "actual"? Do you mean "real" or do you mean "current"?

Comment: "current situation"

Comment: Correct. With the present perfect, "that" a current situation. With simple past, "that" could mean a situation in the past, and "It wasn't always like that" would would mean "that" wasn't representative of the whole time, like if your ex was mostly great, but occasionally got nasty, you could say, "Our relationship wasn't always like that", meaning it also had good moments.

Comment: Also: "actually" is only used to mean "real", not "current".

Comment: What do you mean by "could mean"? ["With simple past, "that" could mean a situation in the past"]  Is it possibility or another thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133515/discussion-between-sergei-and-gotube).